# How can I implement k8s cluster with openstack magnum while openstack api is limited on public api?

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

We have a private deployment of OpenStack and we have another service in front of it to do all API calls.

In OpenStack magnum k8s deployment, the heat container agent is using os-collect-config to access to public API of heat and the k8s cloud manager to talk directly via API. in our scenario we don't provide direct API access. could you please tell me how can I manage this kind of scenario?

the front service is written by python and other team members

Comment: If you can't integrate Kubernetes with your IAAS, then you should consider proceeding as for any bare-metal kubernetes deployment. While you might still be able to automate provisioning of your nodes, using terraform or whatever stack you have available, ... Tools such as KubeSpray could be useful, managing Kubernetes on bare-metal hardware

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. But I was wondering Is there any way to find all those APIs  requests and customize their flows and make them compatible for our use?

Comment: I wanna use other magnum power such as upgrading and autohealing